# How can I make this Scala function (a "flatMap" variant) tail recursive?

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

I'm having a look at the following code

http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/p26.scala

Specifically

```
def flatMapSublists[A,B](ls: List[A])(f: (List[A]) => List[B]): List[B] = 
    ls match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case sublist@(_ :: tail) => f(sublist) ::: flatMapSublists(tail)(f)
    }
```

I'm getting a StackOverflowError for large values presumably because the function is not tail recursive.  Is there a way to transform the function to accommodate large numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is definitely not tail recursive.  The `f(sublist) :::` is modifying the results of the recursive call, making it a plain-old-stack-blowing recursion instead of a tail recursion.

One way to ensure that your functions are tail recursive is to put the `@annotation.tailrec` on any function that you expect to be tail recursive.  The compiler will report an error if it fails to perform the tail call optimization.

For this, I would add a small helper function that's actually tail recursive:

```
def flatMapSublistsTR[A,B](ls: List[A])(f: (List[A]) => List[B]): List[B] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def helper(r: List[B], ls: List[A]): List[B] = {
    ls match {
      case Nil => r
      case sublist@(_ :: tail) => helper(r ::: f(sublist), tail)
    }
  }
  helper(Nil, ls)
}
```

<strike>For reasons not immediately obvious to me, the results come out in a different order than the original function.  But, it looks like it works :-)</strike> Fixed.

Comment: Your results come out in the wrong order becuase in the original, you take the current results and append all the remaining results. In your TR version, your list `r` is carrying through all the previous results, so you need to append current results to that list.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to implement the function:

```
scala> def flatMapSublists[A,B](ls: List[A])(f: (List[A]) => List[B]): List[B] =
     |   List.iterate(ls, ls.size)(_.tail).flatMap(f)
flatMapSublists: [A, B](ls: List[A])(f: List[A] => List[B])List[B]
```

A simply comparison between dave's flatMapSublistsTR and mine:

```
scala> def time(count: Int)(call : => Unit):Long = {
     |    val start = System.currentTimeMillis
     |    var cnt =  count
     |    while(cnt > 0) {
     |       cnt -= 1
     |       call
     |    }
     |    System.currentTimeMillis - start
     | }
time: (count: Int)(call: => Unit)Long

scala> val xs = List.range(0,100)

scala> val fn = identity[List[Int]] _
fn: List[Int] => List[Int] = <function1>

scala> time(10000){ flatMapSublists(xs)(fn) }
res1: Long = 5732

scala> time(10000){ flatMapSublistsTR(xs)(fn) }
res2: Long = 347232
```

Where the method flatMapSublistsTR is implemented as:

```
def flatMapSublistsTR[A,B](ls: List[A])(f: (List[A]) => List[B]): List[B] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def helper(r: List[B], ls: List[A]): List[B] = {
    ls match {
      case Nil => r
      case sublist@(_ :: tail) => helper(r ::: f(sublist), tail)
    }
  }
  helper(Nil, ls)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def flatMapSublists2[A,B](ls: List[A], result: List[B] = Nil)(f: (List[A]) => List[B]): List[B] = 
    ls match {
      case Nil => result
      case sublist@(_ :: tail) => flatMapSublists2(tail, result ++ f(sublist))(f)
    }
```

You generally just need to add a result result parameter to carry from one iteration to the next, and spit out the result at the end instead of adding the end to the list.

Also that confusting `sublist@` thing can be simplified to

`case _ :: tail => flatMapSublists2(tail, result ++ f(ls))(f)`

Off-topic: here's how I solved problem 26, without the need for helper methods like the one above. If you can make this tail-recursive, have a gold star.

```
  def combinations[A](n: Int, lst: List[A]): List[List[A]] = n match {
    case 1 => lst.map(List(_))
    case _ => lst.flatMap(i => combinations (n - 1, lst.dropWhile(_ != i).tail) map (i :: _))
  }
```